# Why is std::span a pointer + size and not two iterators

Tags: c++, c++20, std-span

It appears that `std::span` in C++20 is defined similarly to

```
template<class T>
class span
     {
     T* begin;
     size_t count;
     };
```

And not

```
template<class Iter>
class span
     {
     Iter begin;
     Iter end;
     };
```

which is more general (works with std::list, std::map, etc)?

Answer (score 13):

The whole point of `std::span<T>` is to be a view over *contiguous* data. `pair<T*, size_>` (or something like it) is the right way to represent that view. You cannot have a `std::span` that is a view over a `std::list` or a `std::map`, so it doesn't make sense to come up with a way to represent it. The point is to be a common, vocabulary type to just accept contiguous data.

It's also very important `span` is effectively type-erased. A `span<int>` could refer into a `int[20]` or a `vector<int>` or a `int[]` that is dynamically allocated somewhere or a `llvm::SmallVector<int>` or a ... It doesn't matter where it comes from, you just have the one type that is: "view over some contiguous `int`s".

It is true that `pair<Iter, Iter>` (or, more generally, `pair<Iter, Sentinel>`) is a more general representation that would work for more containers. There is such a thing in C++20 as well, it's called `std::ranges::subrange<I, S>`. But note here that we don't have the type-erasure aspect... a `subrange` over a `map<K, V>` will have a different type than a `subrange` over a different container with the same `value_type`, like `list<pair<K const, V>>` or `vector<pair<K const, V>>` or `multimap<K, V>`.

Comment: But you could then use subrange everywhere you would otherwise use a span. Is the reason for different types then that you can provide a more optimal implementation if you use a separate class for the simple case?

Comment: @user877329 It's not a question of "optimal"... `subrange<T*>` is basically equivalent to `span<T>` in terms of representation. But they have different usability. `vector<T>` is definitely convertible to `span<T>`, but not necessarily to `subrange<T*>`. Also the template parameters have different meaning, `T` vs `T*`. `span` is just the more specific thing for the more specific use-case.

Comment: @user877329: "*But you could then use subrange everywhere you would otherwise use a span.*" No, you can't. You can pass a `span`'s data to a C API; you can't do that with an arbitrary iterator subrange.

Comment: @Barry `subrange<T*> range{vec.data(), vec.data() + size()};`, if subrange ctor accepts the two iterators.

Comment: @NicolBolas I should be able to do so if `Iter` is a pointer. Also, even if I could pass it to a C API, there has to exist such API, and most C API:s use a pointer and a size, and not a span struct so C compatibility is not a huge deal unless you rewrite POSIX or Windows API, and a bunch of other C libraries, which you don't. Sure, it could happen that calling `foo(T*, size_t)` looks exactly the same in assembly as `foo(std::span<T>)`, but force a different function signature is definitely UB.

Comment: @user877329 That's not the same thing as convertible. And Nicol said the span's data, not the span itself.

Comment: @user877329: "*there has to exist such API, and most C API:s use a pointer and a size, and not a span*" The point *isn't* that you can literally pass `std::span` to a C API. It's that, if your function takes a `span`, you can pass the guts of that `span` to a C API. You can't do that with an iterator-based one, not unless you force the iterator type to be a pointer. And even then, you don't get all of the useful features of `span`, such as implicit conversions from contiguous ranges.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas "you don't get all of the useful features of span, such as implicit conversions from contiguous ranges." Aha, so the additional type *is* to enable more convenience features, that would have never worked (or wouldn't work well) on other iterators.