# Use std::span or std::ranges::contiguous_range when wrapping C arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm writing a C++ library that has to externally expose a C API. While doing it, I find myself questioning what is the better way to wrap the C idiomatic pair of `(pointer, size)`. I find myself having a hard time choosing between [`std::ranges::contiguous_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/contiguous_range) and [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Where I am right now is that, while `contiguous_range` is more generic, `span` seems more natural for this use case. The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56811477/6178613) says that `span` erases the type of the container, or maybe makes it irrelevant. Which is good for me, as this is embedded and code size matters. Also, I can not use anything that would not compile under GCC 10 (so most, if not all, of C++20 is okay).

Are there any pros or cons to using one over the other in my use case?

A small sample of the two options - both working.

Option 1 - the one I initially went with - is to use [`std::ranges::contiguous_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/contiguous_range), like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept contiguous_uint8_range =
    std::ranges::contiguous_range<T> && std::is_same_v<uint8_t, std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>;

[[nodiscard]] static inline int read(
    const struct i2c_controller* controller, uint8_t addr_7b, contiguous_uint8_range auto output_buffer
) {
    if (controller->read == nullptr) return I2C_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    return controller->read(
        controller->context, addr_7b, std::ranges::size(output_buffer), std::to_address(output_buffer.begin())
    );
}
```

Option 2 is to use [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span), like this:

```cpp
template<std::size_t Extent = std::dynamic_extent>
using u8_span = std::span<uint8_t, Extent>;

template<std::size_t Extent = std::dynamic_extent>
[[nodiscard]] static inline int read(
    const struct i2c_controller* controller, uint8_t addr_7b, u8_span<Extent> output_buffer
) {
    if (controller->read == nullptr) return I2C_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    return controller->read(controller->context, addr_7b, output_buffer.size(), output_buffer.data());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I find myself having a hard time choosing between `std::ranges::contiguous_range` and `std::span`.

That's not a choice. All you're doing is deciding where the template is. `span` has a template constructor conditioned on `contiguous_range` (and `sized_range`, which your version also needs to use). So you're either writing a template function, or you're requiring that the user invoke a template function through `span`'s constructor.

A template is being specialized either way.

I'd pick `span` because someone else already wrote the code for you. As I noted, your version isn't as good as it doesn't consider that the range may not be a `sized_range`. Since it's easy to get wrong, it's best to let someone else do it.

Comment: A good point, I missed the constructor accepting a range.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're in an embedded context, the `std::span` version has an advantage for you: `std::span<uint8_t>` is a concrete type, not a template type (or concept), which means that there will only be one copy of your `read` function in the code memory of the MCU (unless it gets inlined somewhere). The `ranges` version may result in a copy of the function being generated whenever you call it with a different range type.

In fact, since any `std::span<uint8_t, N>` is convertible to a `std::span<uint8_t>` (with dynamic extent), you could make `read` a plain function instead of a function template:

```
[[nodiscard]] static inline int read(
    const struct i2c_controller* controller, uint8_t addr_7b, std::span<uint8_t> output_buffer
) {
    if (controller->read == nullptr) return I2C_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    return controller->read(controller->context, addr_7b, output_buffer.size(), output_buffer.data());
}
```

Since a dynamic-extent `std::span` contains just a pointer and a size, this is exactly equivalent to the C version of passing separate pointer and size parameters.

Additionally, any contiguous range of `uint8_t` can be converted to a `std::span<uint8_t>` as well, which means that the version using ranges has no advantage at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use `std::span`, but not the way you're doing.

You just want:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] static inline int read(
    const struct i2c_controller* controller, uint8_t addr_7b, std::span<u8> output_buffer);
```

In this context, you do not care about the actual source type - you just want a view onto it. The original approach using `contiguous_range`  requires a new instantiation for every source type (which you don't need) but more importantly is actively wrong in most use-cases.

```cpp
u8 c_array[100];
std::array<u8, 100> cpp_array;
std::vector<u8> v;

// this one doesn't compile
read(..., c_array);

// these compile, but you're copying the container
// into the function, and writing into that copy
// the actual containers I'm passing in are unchanged
read(..., cpp_array);
read(..., v);
```

The advantage of using `std::span<u8>` (not a template) is that all of these work and do the right thing. If you make it a template, none of these compile and have to instead be explicitly converted into the function - which is utterly pointless syntactic noise, as you basically have no reason of supporting fixed extent.

If you ever find yourself asking the question "contiguous_range or span?" the answer is always span, since the former almost never makes sense in the context where the latter is a viable option.